# Using Bing maps with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bing-maps

I have the following HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/IndexView.js"></script>    
</head>
<body onload="LoadMap();">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <h2>Where do you want to go?</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">        
        <div id="pnlMap">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div style="align-content:center">
            <h3>Test</h3>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And IndexView.js:

```
function LoadMap() {
    var map = new VEMap('pnlMap');
    map.LoadMap();
}
```

What I end up with is a page where the map starts at the very top left of the web page.  What I want is for the map to appear beneath the text **Where do you want to go?**.

As I understand the way that bootstrap "rows" work, they should appear sequentially on the page and, if I replace the map with text, that is exactly what happens; so, is there something about Bing Maps that breaks this rule.  Looking [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259692.aspx) what I'm doing appears to be correct.

Comment: I can't see bootstrap library loaded...

Comment: Bootstrap is loaded by a bundle in the _Layout.cshtml.  I left it out because it just crowded the question.

Comment: Looks like you are using Bing Maps V6.3 which is deprecated as of last November and will be turned off soon. You should migrate your app to Bing Maps V8 which has a lot more features and is much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired layout after adding `style="position:relative; width:400px;"` to the `div` containing the map.

```js
function LoadMap() {
  var map = new VEMap('pnlMap');
  map.LoadMap();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script>

<body onload="LoadMap();">
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <h2>Where do you want to go?</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="pnlMap" style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div style="align-content:center">
        <h3>Test</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

or better you can also give width in percentage as `width:50%`

Comment: Many thanks - adding position relative works great.  Why?  Surely whatever the default / bootstrap setting for this would apply to text - so why, when I replace a map with text, don't I get the text behaving the same way?

Comment: it seems by default if we don't provide any positioning it takes it as 'static
'.